# How to Change UIscreen mainscreen brightness

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How to change `[UIScreen mainScreen]` 's brightness value in iOS earlier to iOS5.0
we can use '`brightness`' in iOS5.0. what is the alternative in iOS 4.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No way to deal with brightness directly on iOS < 5.0 . However, it exists a trick : you can add a UIView (with black background) on your main view and change the alpha value (of your black uiview).